# Incorrect screen resolution is retrieved using HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.width").ToString()

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have developed a web page using [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight). When I tried to retrieve the screen resolution of my PC (which is set to 1366 X 768) using the C# code,

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     string width = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.width").ToString();
     string Height = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.height").ToString();            
}
```

it shows the incorrect screen resolution, as 1024 X 768.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
 var width = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.availWidth");

 var height = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.availHeight");
```

Comment: Now it shows different screen resolution as (1366 X 666) but still the incorrect screen resolution

Comment: 102 pixels for menu + statusbar doesn't seem strange.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not the screen size that you want to know about, and not the window size, you might use `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` and `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`.

You might also find it useful to do some computation with your window's size, the `SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight`, `SystemParameters.ResizeFrameHorizontalBorderHeight`, and `SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth`.

All this works fine with standards windows, if you use a 'ToolWindow' WindowStyle, you might need other values.

Note that depending on OS (Windows XP and Windows Vista at least), the figures provided may be 'strange' because they are scaled with a DPI parameter I sometimes found hard to understand (on Windows Vista I develop a program that targets Windows XP, and both do not behave the same). For sure: if you have a wide screen (which is your case), the DPI parameter is automaticly changed on Windows Vista and is not the default 96 DPI. To solve those issues, have a look at `PresentationSource`, and its member `CompositionTarget`.

The following code will give you the real coordinates/sizes and not the ones changed by the DPI setting.

```
var PS = PresentationSource.FromVisual(MyWindow);
var realX = myX* PS.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
var realY = myY* PS.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
```